# Best data type for a simple reservation system in java

Tags: java, list, dictionary, types, hashmap

I'm trying to create a trivially simple reservation system to practice TDD. I initially tried an ArrayList with a set number of spaces representing times, then a Map and both seemed close, but neither ultimately worked.
Immutibilty is key and I've used a constructor to set the capacity and am trying to have the setter depend on the empty-string-ness or nullabilty (tried both) of the String value:

```
public class BookingSystem {

    private BookingSystem bookingSystem;
    private Map<Integer, String> classList;

    public HashMap<Integer, String> setClassList() {
        for (int i=0;i<24; i++) {
            classList.put(0, "");
        }
        return classList;
    }

    public void bookClassroom(int time, String room) throws BookedException {
        if (classList.get(time).equals("")) {
            classList.put(time, room);
        } else {
                throw new BookedException();
        }
    }
```

This seems like a hack, but also seems logical to me. Is a HashMap overkill and would a simple list or array suffice? I've tried them all but haven't quite hit it and now I feel like now I'm overly mired in the many, many Java data structures.

Next step would be to make Classrooms its own class and an enum, but first I have to get the basics down!

- edit: Stuck behind a firewall that's not allowing me to comment on others' posts. Each index of the array/list/map should suffice as "an hour". the list will be 8 or 24 indices long (it doesn't matter, thus performance is not an issue).

Comment: Far too much debate, man... Anf i am sure there'll be one different and unique design for eqch one of us apporting ideas...

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on the booking. If the set of reservation slots is small (reservations unit is an hour, school is open from 9am to 5pm), then you could have each hour as a key in a map structure. But then, if your booking application is used for more than one day, you'll have to associate a date (ddmmyyyy) to a map (Map>).

If the booking times are complex (can be from 8:20 to 11:10), you'd have a Booking entity with a booking start date, a booking end date and a classroom field. Then you would implement the booking logic in a method that would interact with the bookings database. The method would check if there's a booking that would collide with the booking we want to create. If it's the case, the method raises an exception; else a new booking is created.

To get a better understanding of which Java structure to use, you'd have to know the particularities of each one. There's a brief summary [here](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Java_Collections_Overview)

Answer (score 0):

The "immutability" constraint makes a Hashmap/table significantly harder to implement because your table will get pretty bloated.

The runtime in a Hashtable is O(1) amortized. However, hashtables suffer from becoming too dense, resulting in a runtime of O(N). I believe that rehashing makes this case very rare, and reduces the runtime back to O(1).

If you are implementing an ArrayList, the runtime is O(N) worst-case. However, if you know the exact location of an element it is O(1) runtime. Overall, as your number of reservations grows, you are going to have a much higher average runtime for search/insert/delete when using the ArrayList.

To provide the most efficiency you would have to grow your structure by n/2 elements every time that the current ArrayList fills. This may not seem bad at first, but what happens when you have some very large number of possible reservations? Your resources are tied down in a significant way.

---

Personally, I would attempt to implement an ***[AVL-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)***. This follows the Binary Search tree property, which would keep your reservation times in order, and also keep your tree balanced at the same time (saving you space and search/insert/delete runtime).

An AVL-Tree gives you a runtime of O(log N) for search insert and delete, and a worst-case space of O(N). The AVL-Tree would perform significantly better than a Hashmap/table of ArrayList as your number of reservations grows.